# Converting an existing set of QPushButtons to a single array

Tags: c++, qt

I'm an absolute beginner at both Qt and C++, so please forgive me.

I'm writing a desktop calendar app. I have 42 pushbuttons for displaying the day numbers, which, when clicked, will put up an edit field for adding a note. These buttons are already made and in place. They all work, but I'd like to make them into a single array, for ease of coding. Can anyone please suggest how I can do this? I've searched the documentation, but I don't really understand it.

Thanks in advance for your indulgence.

Comment: Did you put the buttons to their positions by hand in Creator's form editor?

Comment: I'd say using a [QVector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvector.html) should help you, and you can `.append()` each pushbutton into it, and access using the `.at` and `.operator[]` operator and member functions for each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Qvector like this:

```
QVector<QPushButton*> btns;
btns.append(oldbuttonname);
```

I recommend looping through all the buttons instead of manually putting them in one by one. What I mean is getting rid of the earlier buttons you had, and create non-named objects in the [`QVector`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvector.html). Here is an example:

```
QVector<QPushButton*> btns(42);
for (int i=0;i<btns.size();i++)
{
    btns[i] = new QPushButton(/*constructor args*/);
}
//Access like this
btns[0]->member_name();
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. Yes, the buttons were put in manually with the Qt designer. I'm sure I'll be able to sort it now. Thank you again.

Comment: Please take the moment to mark this answer correct by clicking the checkmark icon on the left, so others can see this was correct. The icon will turn green when clicked.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah, use either QVector constructing with size and add assign elements by `[] operator` or just create blank container and then use `.append()`. You do not want to have 84 elements in your vector, do you?

Comment: @MateuszKwasniak I fixed the error, and thanks for pointing it out. I guess I wasn't paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **array or any other container** (like QVector) of widgets (pointers to widgets) to gather all of those in one place. You can both create new object or assign already existing ones, i.e:

```
QVector<QPushButton*> buttons;
buttons.append(new QPushButton());
```

Eventually for your **already existing buttons**:

```
QVector<QPushButton*> buttons;
buttons.append(ui->pushButton);
buttons.append(ui->pushButton_2);
//etc..
```

Then you can just access them like typical elements of array:

```
buttons[0]->height = 50;
buttons[1]->setVisible(false);
```